# how to know graphic current user(s) and DISPLAY(s) by root

Tags: bash, shell-script, graphics, openrc, loginctl

Gentoo, openrc, X11.

Hi,

For my suspend process, I need to get something like

```
[user] [DISPLAY]
```

for example:

```
chris :0
```

I can do it with:

```
for sessionid in $(/bin/loginctl list-sessions --no-legend | awk '{ print $1 }'); do
       /bin/loginctl show-session -p Display -p Name --value $sessionid | sed ':a;N;s/\n/ /'
done
```

BUT I need my script is used by root (suspend script in /etc/elogind/system-sleep/), and that's why I need to know user and display to use.
And when used by root (script), `/bin/loginctl list-sessions` seems to not give any result. (used by root in a terminal works well)

What is the best, robust way to achieve this please?
Currently, I use:

```
if [ -S /tmp/.X11-unix/X* ] ; then
         display=":$(ls /tmp/.X11-unix/X* 2>/dev/null | sed 's#/tmp/.X11-unix/X##' | head -n 1)"
         if [ -n "$display" ]; then
                 user=$(who | grep '('$display')' | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u | head -n1)
                 [ -n "$user" ] && echo $user $display
         fi
fi
```

But I don't find it really very clean, even if it works very well for me.

Comment: Note that you can have multiple X server running on the same machine (including but not limited to Xorg ones). I suppose the information you really want is the "current" tty (and the Xorg that runs on top of it, if any)?

Comment: @TomYan This is what I would prefer ideally, but if I have them all it doesn't matter, that's why I indicated user(s) and DISPLAY(s) in the title. The important thing is to get them as root by the suspend script.

Comment: @TomYan so ? what next ?